# Insert Statement gives an error msg for multiple lines - "Missing Value in the Form"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a batch of 800 Insert statement, but get the error message `"Missing value in the form"`. If I run each statement separately it works just fine. I've tried troubleshooting it and found that if:

1. If I edit the statement by changing the line delimiter from `;` to `:` it works! Also,
2. If I copy and paste the quote from the `Timestamp` field to the `Data` field it works!

The problem is I have 800 plus entries and there must be a better way!

Here is a sample of the code:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_cp_bp`(`uid`, `business_category_id`, `data`, `points`, `timestamp`) VALUES (17,17,"36",100,"2014-04-01 16:36:18");
INSERT INTO `wp_cp_bp`(`uid`, `business_category_id`, `data`, `points`, `timestamp`) VALUES (17,22,"36",100,"2014-04-01 16:36:18");
INSERT INTO `wp_cp_bp`(`uid`, `business_category_id`, `data`, `points`, `timestamp`) VALUES (3,5,"60",200,"2014-04-01 16:36:18");
INSERT INTO `wp_cp_bp`(`uid`, `business_category_id`, `data`, `points`, `timestamp`) VALUES (2,7,"195",300,"2014-04-01 16:36:18");
```

Comment: weird there has been a lot of questions on this.. are u using phpmyadmin ? since the issue looks like something related to phpmyadmin from previous questions.

Comment: Had the same trouble with PhpMyAdmin. Can you parse the data to have a single Insert statement? `INSERT (field1, field2) VALUES ('x', 'y'), ('z', 'a'), ...